# related to query using SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

In oracle sql, how to get the count of newly added customers only for the month of april and may and make sure they werent there in the previous months

```
SELECT CUSTOMER ID , COUNT(*)
FROM TABLE
WHERE DATE BETWEEN '1-APR-2018' AND '31-MAY-2018' AND ...
```

If we give max (date) and min(date), we can compare the greater date to check if this customer is new , correct?

expected output is month count 
                  april --- 
                   may ---

should show the exact count how many new customers joined in these two months

Comment: Please include sample data, table definitions and expected output, Also how would you check for previous months if they are new customers ?

Comment: Generally speaking, you need to use `count` function to calculate a count, use a date condition in WHERE clause to filter out months other than april and may, and use NOT EXISTS subquery to check if customer is present in previous months or not. Your question is too general to give you some more specific tips. I vote to close this question as `too broad`.

Comment: This question is a good question for Stack Overflow.  Someone would whip up some SQL for you, and it would all work out fine.  That said, it definitely needs more detail.  What fields does your table have?  What does a small sample selection look like?  What are the formats of the fields?  I'm sorry you got downvoted but you really need to have enough information in the question for people to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach is to use aggregation:

```
select customer_id, min(date) as min_date
from t
group by customer_id
having min(date) >= date '2018-04-01 and
       min(date) < date '2018-06-01';
```

This gets the list of customers (which your query seems to be doing).  To get the count, just use `count(*)` and make this a subquery.